# Changing the first row name conditionally on character interval in SAS

Tags: sas, export

Consider the following data:

```
data GDP;
   input Year $ Agriculture Industry;
datalines;
2016 195 1634
2017 220 1986
;
```

When exporting as a .dat file:

```
proc export
   data    = GDP
   outfile = '....\GDP.dat'
   dbms    = TAB
   replace;
run;
```

Then I get the following file:

[image]

However, I want the following file:

[image]

Where:

- `Mydata` is a text I manually add.
- The number after for instance `Year` (that is `Year: 1-4`) is the character intervals where the values are within. For instance, the values in the `Year` column is from characther 1 to 4. The values in the `agriculture` column goes from 9 to 11, and so on.

So SAS should count the interval for the values and add it to the first row name. How to do it in SAS?

Comment: It is hard to tell from the photo graphs what characters you actually want in the first row of the DAT file.  Where are the tabs in that string?  Or do the numbers with the hyphens between them mean that you actually want a fixed column file instead of tab delimited file you are currently creating?

Comment: Not sure you want `dbms=tab`. With tab delimiting, Agriculture would start at char 6 explicitly and only be 9 if tabs expanded to every 8th position by program processing the `GDP.dat`  What program is consuming the .dat ? If it is an existing program (such as a legacy production custom written .exe) you probably want to write a DATA Step to create the .dat file.  If for Excel, you don't need the field locations.

Comment: Here is an outline of how you create a fixed width file - note that it's pretty manual as you do need to specify the locations. https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/faq/how-do-i-write-out-a-fixed-format-file-in-sas/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fudge this with labels to your variables and then add the LABEL option to PROC EXPORT.

```
data GDP;
   input Year $ Agriculture Industry;
label Year = "Mydata, Year:1-4" Agriculture = "Agriculture:9-11";
   datalines;
2016 195 1634
2017 220 1986;
run;

proc export
   data    = GDP
   outfile = '....\GDP.dat'
   dbms    = TAB
   LABEL
   replace;
run;
```

FYI - it looks like you're trying to create a fixed width file and put the specifications in the header. I'd advise against this and either put the specifications in a separate file or to include it at the top of the file instead.
Putting it in the header makes it harder for any other system to process correctly.

If you really need this for some reason, you may also want to consider using a data step to create your export instead of using PROC EXPORT.

AFAIK there is no easy way to define the specifications automatically though you could push the PROC CONTENTS output to a separate data set.